# what is the difference between application insights Collection level

Tags: azure-application-insights

On azure portal, I can setup application insights to collect basic or recommended collection level. However, I am bit confused on what the difference between these? From microsoft doc:

```
.NET Basic collection level offers essential single-instance APM capabilities.

.NET Recommended collection level:
        Adds CPU, memory, and I/O usage trends.
        Correlates micro-services across request/dependency boundaries.
        Collects usage trends, and enables correlation from availability results to transactions.
        Collects exceptions unhandled by the host process.
        Improves APM metrics accuracy under load, when sampling is used.
```

When I enabled just basic collection level, seems I can still see data in application map and dependency boundary seems still work (as appInsight portal seems to show database calls even with basic collection).

Does anyone know what basic collection level actually collects?

Comment: Did you have app insights sdk installed in your web project?

Answer (score 1):

Basic level is a subset of the full Application Insights capabilities. It'll still collect requests and dependencies, but you wont be able to correlated traces from multiple services. (i.e if A and B are 2 services with own ikey, both on Basic level, the E2E transaction view will not be able to show request/dependency flow between them. In Recommended mode, they will be shown as correlated.)

The exact set of differences between basic vs recommended is not documented, and is subject to change with every release.